# Render() returning undefined when using Field from react-form

Tags: javascript, redux, redux-form

When trying to create a simple redux-form I get the following error

> Warning: React.createElement: type should not be null, undefined, boolean, or number. It should be a string (for DOM elements) or a ReactClass (for composite components). Check the render method of `SearchProductsForm`.

This is my form component, I'm only using standard components, and the import statements are copied from the SimpleForm example.

```
import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react';
import { Field, reduxForm } from 'redux-form';
const { DOM: { input } } = React;

@reduxForm({
  form: 'searchProducts',
  fields: ['name']
})
export default
class SearchProductsForm extends Component {

  static propTypes = {
    name: PropTypes.string,
    handleSubmit: PropTypes.func.isRequired
  };

  render() {
    const { handleSubmit } = this.props;
    return (
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
          <div>
            <label htmlFor="name">Name</label>
              <Field name="name" component={input} type="text" placeholder="Last Name"/>
          </div>
          <button type="submit">Submit</button>
      </form>
    );
  }
}
```

If I remove the following row the component renders

```
<Field name="name" component={input} type="text" placeholder="Name"/>
```

This is my calling component

```
import React, {Component, PropTypes} from 'react';
import Helmet from 'react-helmet';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import * as productActions from 'redux/modules/products';
import {isLoaded, load as loadProducts} from 'redux/modules/products';
import { asyncConnect } from 'redux-async-connect';
import { SearchProductsForm } from 'components';

@asyncConnect([{
  deferred: true,
  promise: ({store: {dispatch, getState}}) => {
    if (!isLoaded(getState())) {
      return dispatch(loadProducts());
    }
  }
}])

@connect(
  state => ({
    products: state.products.data,
    error: state.products.error,
    loading: state.products.loading,
    value: ''
  }),
  {...productActions })

export default class Products extends Component {
  static propTypes = {
    products: PropTypes.array,
    error: PropTypes.string,
    loading: PropTypes.bool,
    load: PropTypes.func.isRequired,


  };

  handleSubmit = ( values ) => {
    console.log( values );
  }

  render() {
    const {products} = this.props;
    return (
      <div>
        <Helmet title="Products"/>
          <SearchProductsForm onSubmit={this.handleSubmit} />
            {products.map((product) =>
              <tr key={product._id}>
                <td>{product._id}</td>
                <td>{product._source.title}</td>
              </tr>)
            }
          }
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: you are passing `input` variable to `component={input}`, it mean to render the `Field` component with a custom component called `input`. If you just want to render a default input, you should just pass in `"input"` as in `component="input"`, refer more examples from [http://redux-form.com/6.4.3/docs/api/Field.md/#usage](http://redux-form.com/6.4.3/docs/api/Field.md/#usage)

Comment: Thank you for the reply, unfortunately I get the same error when trying your suggestion. I had a look at the API documentation, but it did not help me. I have tried to follow the Simple Form example at http://redux-form.com/6.0.0-alpha.4/examples/simple/ which uses {input} from React

Answer (score 0):

I was using redux-form 3.0, when I updated to 6 it works as expected